# Android Studio ViewFlipper

Tags: android, viewflipper

I need help to to write the codes whereby the Viewflipper would only flip between images upon pressing a button. When a right arrow key is pressed, it would flip to next image on  the right and if a left arrow key is pressed, it would flip to the image on the left. Just started out developing applications and hence not very sure of how to go about doing it. Thanks !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442287/using-viewflipper-with-onclick-to-switch-views

Comment: https://sripatim.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/viewflipper-on-button-click-in-android/